# How do I compile an Ember action in a JavaScript string?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Within my Ember component `items-map.js`, I am invoking a Google Map. The Google Map API allows me to have infoWindows (the bubbles that open once you click any pin on the map).

I have some HTML content inside these bubbles and clicking on a link within it, should transition to another route. I'm trying to achieve this using an action within the component but in order to do that I need to first be able to encode the Handlebars syntax into the HTML of the infoWindow.

The JavaScript string looks like this:

```
var infoWindowContent = '<a class="btn" href="javascript:void(0);" {{action "routeToItem"}}>See Items</a>';
```

As you can see, I have a Handlebars action within the string. While the button gets rendered, the Handlebars action does not get compiled. I tried wrapping the above string in a `Handlebars.compile()' method like this:

```
var infoWindowContent = Ember.Handlebars.compile('var infoWindowContent = '<a class="btn" href="javascript:void(0);" {{action "routeToItem"}}>See Items</a>';');
```

This produced an error. Instead of getting the button, I now see the text `[object Object]` where the button is supposed to be. How can I fix this?

Comment: Could you post the entire component? I wouldn't user Ember actions for this. I don't think that'll work. Instead, I would setup your own custom event listeners with plain ole javascript or jQuery and then activate Ember code in the handlers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have also same issue, But i have approached in this way using jquery sure it will work, try it.

```
var infoWindowContent = "<span class=\"tooltip-text\">" +
                       "<span class=\"infowIndow\">" +
                       "<a href=\"#/vehicle/<%= uuid %>\"><%= name %></a>" +
                      "</span>" +
                      "<span class=\"tool-tip firstItem-tool-tip\"><%= tool_tip_name %></span></span>";

 var t = this;
 var vehicle_uuid = 'aBCfdf';
 var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: infoWindowContent
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: uluru,
    map: map
  });

  marker.addListener('click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);

    $('.infowIndow').on('click', function() {
        // as I am also doing in component I am using t.get('targetObject')
       t.get('targetObject').transitionToRoute('vehicle.history', vehicle_uuid);
   });
  });
```